# NSTimer Class Methods, and Invalidation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

If I use:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

How can I invalidate this, as it's a class method I don't have access to a pointer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make something like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

(note ":" after myMethod)

```
- (void) myMethod: (id) sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]])
    {
        NSTimer* timer = (NSTimer*) sender;
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks or I guess I could have the NSTimer as an ivar, I was just expecting there to be a 'Invalidate all timers call I guess.

Answer (score 1):

It's a class method that returns a timer. You invalidate that timer.

Comment: OK, how can I invalidate the timer without a reference to it?

Comment: To clarify, I don't have NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduler.....]   I just call [NSTimer ....] thus I do not have a reference to the returned object, unless i'm missing something?

Comment: The class method always returns a pointer; you're just choosing to not keep it. Storing it in an ivar is the most straightforward, if you want to invalidate a repeating timer under certain conditions.

Comment: For non-repeating timers, they automatically invalidate after firing.